# measure deviation across next N rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This question is building on a previous question here: [create new column that compares across rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353195/create-new-column-that-compares-across-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/35353380?noredirect=1#comment58994229_35353380)

I would like to make a new column that checks to see if any of the next n rows differ by more than X.  For example, if we had a dataframe and the next 4 rows differed by more than 1, then the new value would be 0.  If the next 4 rows differed by less than or equal to 1 then the new value would be 1.

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [5,6,4,3,5]})
>>> df
   A
0  5
1  6
2  4
3  3
4  5
>>> desired_result = pandas.DataFrame({"A": [5,6,7,8,2], "new":     [1,1,0,0,0]})
>>> desired_result
   A  new
0  5    1
1  6    0
2  4    1
3  3    0
4  5    0
```

In the example above, the value of 5 becomes a 1 because the absolute difference between the next two values is <= 1 (abs(5-6) = 1 and abs(5-4) = 1).

Similar to the answer provided in the above post, I tried to solve the case with the following code:

```
df['new'] = 1
df.loc[abs(df.A -  df.A.shift(-1)) > 1 , 'new'] = 0
```

This code works when looking at just the next row, but I am not sure what the best way to extend it to n rows will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 2  # Number of following rows
x = 1  # Differ by more than 'x'.

>>> pd.concat([(df.A - df.A.shift(-i - 1)).abs().le(x) 
               for i in range(n)], axis=1).any(axis=1) * 1
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```

The shift is performed `n` times and compared to the current value, resulting in the following boolean values:

```
# shift-1 shift-2
       A      A
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
4  False  False
```

These results are then compared across rows, looking for any true value. Finally, the boolean result is multiplied by one to turn it into ones and zeroes.

```
`pd.concat(...).any(axis=1) * 1`
```

Comment: Thanks! The only change I made was to use .all instead of .any as I wanted to make sure that all of the n values were <= x as opposed to any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`rolling_max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_max.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

E.g., if the period is 2, then

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [5,6,4,3,5]})
>>> pd.rolling_max(df.A.shift(-1), 2).shift(-1)    
0     6
1     4
2     5
3   NaN
4   NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

gives the maximum of the next 2 periods (note the two `NaN`s at the end, where things are just not defined).

In general, for a window of size `k`, you'd use

```
pd.rolling_max(df.A.shift(-1), k).shift(k - 1)
```

From this point, you can just compare your original series subtracted by 1 to the result:

```
df.A - 1 > pd.rolling_max(...
```